# SQL-99 specification, is it specified to first order the result and limit it afterwards?

Tags: sql, specifications, standards, standardization

If I wrote this in MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY bar LIMIT 1
```

it would first order the result and limit it afterwards. I always get the lowest bar.

I wonder if this is specified like this in SQL-standards and how to check that?

All I found are some BNF's which do not explain how something should work, but only what syntax is valid.

Comment: The limit syntax is most definitely not standard in sql, however if you are referring to the fact that limits are applied after the initial query, I think that is standard behavior, otherwise "ORDER BY" and query limits would be mutually exclusive.

Comment: If it's worth about 200 bucks to you the official standard should be the [ISO/IEC 9075](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=53681) document (There are a few more, so it could become rather expensive). (The default sort order as far as I'm aware is 'ascending', at least that's what every book I've seen by now claims).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL 99 has no `LIMIT`. That is an extension in MySQL (and few other databases) initially [created by PHP's founder Rasmus Lerdorf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasmus_lerdorf#Early_life_and_education).

SQL 2003 added support for a comparable `OFFSET` sytnax of this form:

```
SELECT ... [ ORDER BY ... ]
   OFFSET num {ROW|ROWS} FETCH {FIRST|NEXT} [num] {ROW|ROWS} ONLY
```

Not sure any RDMBS supports that, yet.

For checking such features you can buy the standard from ISO. But as most databases implement things slightly of standard. In practical terms you will do better by checking the manuals of the systems you want to support and proper testing of your application.